# Show data from multiple checkbox in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, checkbox, show

i hope all of you can help me to solve my application problem

my problem is when i would like to show data from my multiple checkbox  , data success to show but just showing my first data that i have check.
example is  i check data 1 ,  data 2 ,  data 3, but the only data 1 are showing on my page.

my controller :

```
function comparison()
    {
        if ($this->input->post('submit')) {
            foreach ($id_product = $this->input->post('id_product') as $rm) {
                $show_compare = $this->Compare->start_compare($rm);
            }
            $data['comparison'] = $show_compare;
            $data['title'] = "Comparison";
            $data['meta_keywords'] = ". . .";
            $data['meta_descriptions'] = ". . .";
            $this->load->view('theme/comparison',$data);
        }
    }
```

My Model :

```
function start_compare($id_product)
    {
        $this->db->select('product.id_subcategory,product.type,product.product_name,specificcategory.specificcategory_name,specification_biostar.*');
        $this->db->join('specification_biostar', 'specification_biostar.id_product = product.id_product', 'left');
        $this->db->join('specificcategory', 'specificcategory.id_specificcategory = product.id_subcategory', 'left');
        $this->db->where('product.id_product', $id_product);
        $sql = $this->db->get('product')->result_array();
        return $sql;
    }
```

my view (option multiple-checkbox) :

```
<div class="box-body">
     <input type="checkbox" name="id_product[]" id="txt" onClick="EnableSubmit3(this)" value="<?php echo $row['id_product']; ?>"><label>Choose</label>
     </div>
```

my view (result data) :

```
 <table class="table">
                <?php foreach ($comparison as $row){ ?>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><?php echo $row['id_product'] ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            </table>
```

Comment: you are storing all check box value in database ??

Comment: you are overwriting $show_compare variable each iteration foreach ($id_product = $this->input->post('id_product') as $rm) {
                $show_compare = $this->Compare->start_compare($rm);
            }    so just use like this  $show_compare[]

Comment: @rajat gupta , no . the multiple checkbox i take from database and when i chect some of those checkbox  just want to show what i check

Comment: @ JYoThI can you give me the example  what should i change the code ?

Comment: replace $show_compare variable with this $show_compare[] array it store the all the values in $show_compare array .

Comment: i was reply the code to be                                                 
$show_compare[] = $this->Compare->start_compare($rm);    $data['comparison'] = $show_compare;                                                      is right ?

Comment: yes right @GustiErlangga

Comment: but <?php echo $row['id_product'] ?> Undefined index: id_product, look at my view(result data)

Answer (score 0):

in your code take $show_compare = array(); before foreach loop and use array_push in foreach.

```
$show_compare = array();
   foreach ($id_product = $this->input->post('id_product') as $rm) {
        array_push($show_compare,$this->Compare->start_compare($rm)); 
   }
   $data['comparison'] = $show_compare;
```

Comment: what the meaning of array_push ?

Comment: The array_push() function inserts one or more elements to the end of an array.